# How to order 2 tables in a union?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to get a list of messages, 1 table is a list of all unread messages, the other a list of all read messages. I want the unread messages ordered by the last time they were updated at so that the most recent message is always at the top.

I've written the following query except I'm getting an error that the order by is not meshing with the union. I tried wrapping both statements in parenthesis but that resulted in the wrong order.

```
SELECT threads.id AS thread, 
       updated_at 
FROM   threads 
WHERE  threads.id IN (SELECT thread_id 
                      FROM   posts 
                      WHERE  posts.id IN (SELECT post_id 
                                          FROM   post_recipients 
                                          WHERE  status = 1 
                                             AND 
                             user_id = 'b1367cad-e1ea-31ba-beb9-2b53559eea17')) 
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC 
UNION 
SELECT thread_id AS thread, 
       updated_at 
FROM   thread_assignments 
WHERE  user_id = 'b1367cad-e1ea-31ba-beb9-2b53559eea17' 
   AND status = 0 
   AND thread_id NOT IN (SELECT threads.id AS thread 
                         FROM   threads 
                         WHERE  threads.id IN (SELECT thread_id 
                                               FROM   posts 
                                               WHERE 
                                posts.id IN (SELECT post_id 
                                             FROM   post_recipients 
                                             WHERE  status = 1 
                                                AND 
       user_id = 'b1367cad-e1ea-31ba-beb9-2b53559eea17')) 
                        ) 
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC;
```

to be clear I don't want the final table ordered by updated_at as this could put a read messages higher than an unread message. I want the 2 tables ordered separately and then glued together.

Comment: What about adding a computed field showing 0 resp 1 and the order by cmp_fld,updated_at

Comment: @Teson could you elaborate?

Comment: SELECT 1 as sorter, threads.id AS thread... etc...

Comment: UNION 
SELECT 2 as sorter, thread_id AS thread, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Teson create an aditional field so you can separate both sorts

```
SELECT threads.id AS thread, 
       updated_at ,
       0 as union_source
FROM   threads 
WHERE  threads.id IN (SELECT thread_id 
                      FROM   posts 
                      WHERE  posts.id IN (SELECT post_id 
                                          FROM   post_recipients 
                                          WHERE  status = 1 
                                             AND 
                             user_id = 'b1367cad-e1ea-31ba-beb9-2b53559eea17')) 
UNION 
SELECT thread_id AS thread, 
       updated_at, 
       1 as union_source
FROM   thread_assignments 
WHERE  user_id = 'b1367cad-e1ea-31ba-beb9-2b53559eea17' 
   AND status = 0 
   AND thread_id NOT IN (SELECT threads.id AS thread 
                         FROM   threads 
                         WHERE  threads.id IN (SELECT thread_id 
                                               FROM   posts 
                                               WHERE 
                                posts.id IN (SELECT post_id 
                                             FROM   post_recipients 
                                             WHERE  status = 1 
                                                AND 
       user_id = 'b1367cad-e1ea-31ba-beb9-2b53559eea17')) 
                        ) 
ORDER  BY 
      union_source,
      updated_at DESC;
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't realize order by could take 2 values.